# Initialising Array is clumsy

Tags: groovy

I currently have the code

```
static  Collection<Object[]> defineObjects() {
    def myObjects = new Object[2][4]

    myObjects[0] = [object11,object12,object13,object14]
    myObjects[1] = [object21,object22,object23,object24]

    return myObjects;
}
```

It is annoying that I have to define the size of the array rather than just initialise it.

Is there a more elegant way to code this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define size of an array. Consider following two examples:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked

@CompileStatic
@TypeChecked
class Objects {

  static void main(String[] args) {
    println defineObjects()
    println defineObjects2()
  }

  static Collection<Object[]> defineObjects() {
    def myObjects = [
      [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()] as Object[],
      [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()] as Object[]
    ]
    return myObjects
  }

  static Object[][] defineObjects2() {
    def myObjects = [
      [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()] as Object[],
      [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()] as Object[]
    ] as Object[][]
    return myObjects
  }
}
```

In case of using `Collection<Object[]>` you can simply add lists and cast them to `Object[]`. In case of two dimensional array you do the same + you cast final list to `Object[][]`.

#### Output

```
[[java.lang.Object@4667ae56, java.lang.Object@77cd7a0, java.lang.Object@204f30ec], [java.lang.Object@e25b2fe, java.lang.Object@754ba872, java.lang.Object@146ba0ac]]
[[java.lang.Object@4dfa3a9d, java.lang.Object@6eebc39e, java.lang.Object@464bee09], [java.lang.Object@f6c48ac, java.lang.Object@13deb50e, java.lang.Object@239963d8]]
```